# Cursor goes to start(left) of the EditText after a character is entered or deleted

Tags: java, android, kotlin, android-edittext, cursor

> everything works as it should except the  problem is that the cursor
> just goes to the start after a character is deleted or inputted, i
> want to it to stay at the same position

This is the code:

```
binding.includeFirstSeekbar.seekBar.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(object : OnSeekBarChangeListener {
            override fun onProgressChanged(seekBar: SeekBar, progress: Int, b: Boolean) {

                val number = java.lang.Double.valueOf(progress.toString())/100
                val dec = DecimalFormat("#,##0.00")
                val credits = dec.format(number)
                binding.seekbarValue.setText(credits)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming, that while you want to change the value in the `EditText` manually, your `SeekBar` also progresses and that will change the value of your `seekbarValue`. That could mess up the cursor's position. The solution for this could be to pause this listener while you are writing in the `EditText`, and then resuming after you are done.

Another thing: you can convert your `progress` value into a `Double` with `.toDouble()`. Or just write `(progress/100).toDouble()`.